# How to convert int32 to float javascript

Tags: javascript, int32

I need to convert values ​​of type `int32` to float values

I have the value of **39900** and I need to convert to **399.00**, or **7400** to convert to **74.00** or **4378** to **43.78**, they are not fixed values.

Comment: divide by 100? all numbers are floats in javascript. [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_encoding)

Comment: If you're trying to *display* those with extra decimal points, just call `.toFixed(2)` which will return the string representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to divide the number by `100`, this will put the last 2 digits in the fractions. You don't need to worry about integer and float weirdness from C-like languages, since in Javascript, all numbers are floats, as @pilchard has pointed out.